# Java 7 Directory WatchService does not detect new files

Tags: java, watchservice

I have implemented a WatchService to listen to a single folder on a Linux (Redhat6) filesystem.
When I drag/drop a file to the folder (via WinSCP) the file is detected and processed. However, when an FTP process drops files in the folder. They are not picked up??

This is the Thread code

```
@Override
public void run() {

    log.info("Starting " + NAME);

    while (mustLive) {

        try {

            // get Event or wait for one
            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
            // log.debug("Event found");

            // we are only interested in Create Events
            List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watchKey.pollEvents();

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : events) {

                // we need to get the Absolute Path, so more code is needed
                // to retrieve it.
                Path dir = (Path) watchKey.watchable();
                Path fullPath = dir.resolve((Path) event.context());

                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {

                    log.debug("Created: " + event.context().toString());
                    // callback to process the file
                    caller.processNotificationFile(fullPath, eps);
                }

                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                    // log.debug("Delete: " + event.context().toString());
                }
                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                    // log.debug("Modify: " + event.context().toString());
                }
            }

            // reset the Watcher for new
            boolean resetOK = watchKey.reset();

            if (!resetOK) {
                log.debug("Reset NOK");
                continue;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            killThread();
        }

    }

}
```

When I delete and drop the same file (that should have been picked up)in the monitored folder it is detected and picked up (so the Watcher is working and up and running). 
So somewhere during the FTP copy something goes wrong. Now the only difference is that the file is FTP-ed to the folder as root, but READ access is ON for all files. When I SCP the file I am another user (the same user that owns the WatcherThread).

Is this the problem, that files owned by another user are not picked up? And if so, how to fix this?

Thanks for your help,
Coen

Update:
I tried to SCP with two different non-root user, then the files are detected and picked up.
I tried to set a umask 0000 on the entire folder, with no effect.

Comment: Have you tried ftp-ing with another "non-root" user?

Comment: The read access on files is not important, what matters is that the _directory_ is readable.

Comment: @fge, folder is readable for all.

Comment: What is the JDK Vendor name? Is it Sun?

Comment: @Fildor, yes we tried to SCP a file using the same account as the WatchService is running in. Then the file is picked up. Files that are added as 'root' are not picked up. All folders AND files have READ rights.

Comment: @shazin its 
java version "1.7.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-b24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: @Coren Damen: OK, same user is interesting, too. But if a different user with same "level" is picked up, too, then it's maybe the root-privileges.

Comment: @Fildor yes, but ALL files have R (?).

Comment: Yes, maybe it *is* a bug. I'd just test it if it is the same behaviour with a different not-root user.

Comment: @Fildor, I tested with two other non-root users, the file is picked up :)

Comment: So, I guess it must have been the root-user's files are not readable by non-root users even if they are "R" ... Didn't find anything about this behaviour yet, though. Maybe it's not Java-Specific but depends on the OS/FileSystem ??

Comment: @Fildor, but they are, I can "vi" them using the JDK user's account.

Comment: My Linux days are too long ago, unfortunately ... I just don't see another difference. Is that an ext3-FileSystem?

Comment: @Fildor, the Linux guys here don't understand it either, I will now try a umask 0000 on the folders so new files get +rwx for all when created....to be continued :)

Comment: What brand and version of linux system is this?